# Can I use grails tag outside of GSP?

Tags: grails, groovy, tags, closures

For example, i can put

```
 <g:createLink controller="user" action="show" />
```

inside a .gsp file and it will work nicely.

But also I'd like to use the same closure `createLink` inside a .groovy file which is not part of the grails views

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use taglib methods from Grails controllers, for example:

```
def userShow = g.createLink(controller:"user", action:"show")
```

For builtin taglibs (or those in the g namespace) you can omit the namespace prefix in the method call.

Comment: There must be more to it than that, using just the above code in a grails controller gives `error=groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: g`.

Comment: there definitely IS more to that! See Matt Christianson's answer on how to resolve the "No such property: g" error.

Comment: I think you must first inject the grailsApplication to the controller with `def grailsApplication`. In services you must first define the 'g' with `def g = gspTagLibraryLookup.lookupNamespaceDispatcher("g")`.

Answer (score 14):

Inject the grailsApplication into your service/filter.

```
def grailsApplication
```

And get the Spring bean.

```
def g = grailsApplication.mainContext.getBean('org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.web.taglib.ApplicationTagLib')
def userShow = g.createLink(controller: 'user', action: 'show')
```

Comment: I searched all over to see how to create links in a service... thanks for posting this!

Answer (score 7):

For unmanaged classes you can reference the `g` taglib with:

```
def g = ApplicationHolder.application.mainContext.getBean('org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.web.taglib.ApplicationTagLib')
```

Answer (score 6):

The native way to do this as of Grails 2.0 outside of controllers (so for services, async jobs, etc) is to use the LinkGenerator class.  Works everywhere and mentioned in the official docs.  See example here

http://mrhaki.blogspot.ca/2012/01/grails-goodness-generate-links-outside.html