# Grails resource paths in controller

Tags: image, grails, resources, controller

Say I'm passing a list of image urls from the server to the frontend.

```
images/
    image1.jpg
    image2.jpg
    image3.jpg
```

Now I'm just listing the file names, but I need to reference the absolute path (`/application/images/image1.jpg`). Basically the equivalent of `${resource}` server side.

Comment: I don't quite understand. Why don't you use ${resource} and pass it to the frontend?

Answer (score 6):

You can call this code in your controller:

```
String pathToImage1 = g.resource(dir: 'images', file: 'image1.jpg', absolute: true)
```

Flag 'absolute' may be skipped.

Comment: what is `g`???? seriously, how did this answer get so many upvotes when it references a nonsensical variable like "`g`"??!!

Comment: Hi @dopatraman, I haven't coded on Grails for a long time but if my memory does not fail me, `g` is an equivalent of `<g:` namespace for tags in controllers' code. So `g.resource` is using of `<g:resource/>` tag in Groovy-code.

Comment: Here are some examples: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1191800/can-i-use-grails-tag-outside-of-gsp

Comment: Thanks. Worked for me

Answer (score 3):

for reading file (cvs, xml, img ,...) from controller I use:

```
def csv = grailsAttributes.getApplicationContext().getResource("/data/jak.csv").getFile()
```

Regards
Tom

Answer (score 1):

You can call tags from controllers - see http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/6.%20The%20Web%20Layer.html#6.2.2.6%20Tags%20as%20Method%20Calls