# using g tags in controller

Tags: grails, filter, tags

I am using the following statement in a filter

> if(g.cookie(name:'abc'))

it prompts an error:
*

> groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: g for class:
>   com.AFilters Possible solutions: log  at
>   com.AFilters$_closure1_closure4_closure10.doCall(AFilters.groovy:77)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)

*

Do I have to import some class to use the statement?
I have used this in controller its not creating any error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always inject grailsApplication, etc.

But for current case, I don't see any reason to use taglib, because controller has access to request and cookies. Try:

```
if (request.cookies.find { it.name == 'abc' }) {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to inject the `grailsApplication` and get the according bean.

See [Can I use grails tag outside of GSP?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5516040/1230366) for further information.

Comment: it prompted a error that cant invoke getBean() on null. The errors solved with request.cookies.find{it.name=='abc'})

Answer (score 0):

In controllers you should be able to use the tagLib code directly, without using the `.g` prefix.

```
if(cookie(name:'abc'))
```

Comment: Error:_No signature of method: com.AFilters.cookie() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.LinkedHashMap) values: [[name:abc]]_ appeared. solved by using request scope