# grails how to output message in tag lib

Tags: grails

I'm trying to pull in a message from message.properties from a taglib, but the output is empty.  I know the taglib is being called because if I output out << 'hello' it works fine.  And my code is defined because if I change the codename to something that doesn't exist in the properties file my IDE highlights the code with red text, indicating it wasn't found.

```
class AccountTagLib {

    def accountType = { attrs, body ->
                out << message(code: 'account.friendlyType.BF')
}
}
```

message.properties:

```
account.friendlyType.BF=Here I am
```

Comment: This code is working fine for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it should work like

```
out << g.message(code: 'account.friendlyType.BF')
```

At least that is how I always use it (successfully). But I also read that you can omit the namespace for builtin taglibs (see answer [Can I use grails tag outside of GSP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1191800/can-i-use-grails-tag-outside-of-gsp/1192314#1192314)) so that yours should work too. If it does not work as I proposed may be the other answers to that question [Can I use grails tag outside of GSP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1191800/can-i-use-grails-tag-outside-of-gsp/1192314) help.

Comment: +1 - omitting the `g.` should also work _provided_ there's nothing else in scope that is also called `message` (e.g. a local variable).  I've got into the habit of always using the explicit `g.` after being tripped up by this caveat once too often...